# Issue: Glassfish 5 after Re-Deployment Websocket no Messages from Server

Tags: websocket, glassfish, payara, glassfish-5, jfs

Currently using Glassfish 5(Payara).
After first serverstart and deployment the Websocket has no issues at all.
After a **Re-Deployment** the handshake between client and server connect, but the **websocket** doesn´t get any messages from our server.

In this minimalized example the method pushContext should send a message, but the websocket gets no message.

```
package com.socket;
import lombok.Getter;
import javax.faces.push.Push;
import javax.faces.push.PushContext;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.io.Serializable;

@ViewScoped
@Named
public class IndexBackingBean implements Serializable {

    @Getter
    private String someString = "Hello";

    @Inject
    @Push(channel = "test-channel")
    private PushContext pushContext;

    private int counter = 0;

    public void clickMe() {
        counter += 1;
        final String msg = "Click #" + counter;
        System.out.println(msg + "!!");
        pushContext.send(msg);
    }
}
```